# How to create resource file for multilanguage in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, multilingual, visual-studio-express

I want to generate Local Resources in Visual Studio Express 2012. Following are the steps given in a book to do it.

1. Open your webpage (markup) in Visual Studio.
2. From the Tools menu select Generate Local Resource. This causes Visual Studio to perform the following tasks:

   - Create the App_LocalResources folder (if necessary).
   - Generate an XML-based local resource file for the webpage in the App_LocalResources folder. This file contains resource settings for page elements (such as the title) and control properties (such as Text, ToolTip, Title, Caption, and other string-based properties).

However, when I try this with VS 2012 web express I can't see Generate local resource option under tools.

[image]

How to fix this issue? Can't we do this with VS Express?

Comment: The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx) strongly suggests that this is not supported in the Express edition.  You need the retail license.

Comment: Thanks, Hans Passant!

Comment: Can I continue my work without this feature? I mean manually handling resource files?

Comment: @HansPassant Please post your answer so the OP can select it as the correct answer and we will see the question as answered ;)